# Geoserver GetCapabilities and CORS

Tags: geoserver, jquery, ajax, cors

Using WMS I do a GetCapabilities request on a GeoServer instance.
This works in FireFox, but not in Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer.

The point is that in the web.xml from the server I did add:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
```

So the XML output does not have anything which will put the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in.

And the case is that in any other request this not an issue, especially when I use jsonp in the jquery AJAX call.

However I didn't find any way to get the Capabilities in a JSON object. 
In other words I am stuck with XML and this doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do the request on jsonp?
If not how do I set-up the server so that the GetCapabilities XML does use the Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you can get the response in JSON; the WMS spec is all XML based.

Comment: Well I didn't think I would be able to get it in JSON, at least, not the GetCapaBilities, others might be possible.

Comment: A WMS GetCapabilities response document is always an XML document, the same is true of all OGC OWS services (such as WFS, WCS, WPS, CSW, SOS).

Comment: `So the XML output does not have anything which will put the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in.` I'm not sure I understand this comment, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin header ` is always in the HTTP header, never in a file whether it be XML or JSON, and this behaviour is configured on the server providing the XML/JSON documents